# How to customize Xamarin.Forms app?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can I customize the appearence of xamarin.forms components?
I want each button to have the same image, for instance. Or for all systems to share the same login screen with the same background image.
I know I can do that by adding one specific screen to each platform project. But I want to be able to customize the component itself. Example: All buttons will have the same background image no matter which platform is running.

I've read these:

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/styles/

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-xamarinforms-customizing-user-interface--cms-22144

The most promising one seems to be the last one. Is a custom renderer the only way to accomplish this? Can't I just add an image at the shared project and it automagicaly works for all platforms?

Thanks.

Comment: to apply a common look to all elements of a certain type, you would use Styles.

Comment: @Jason Thanks Jason, like Xamarin's linked example? (second link)

Comment: Yes.  They also have a guide on working with Images in Forms - http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/

Comment: @Jason Alright, if you could post that as a reply I'd be able to accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not absolutely clear, what **exactly** you want to reach... but I try to answer you.

If you use a **shared** project (based on template "**Blank App (Xamarin.Forms shared**)", you can use the **same** page / page-definition in **all** of your platforms.
You can add - e.g. a login-form in the shared-folder and then call it from code (e.g. from another page in the shared folder).
If you want to create **your own** controls, you can create "user-controls" and use it everywhere you want (what I recommend to every user).
You do this, by create a **own** class (e.g. with an Entry and a Label), implement the events and then instantiate it where you want to use it. E.G.

```
var OeFirma = new EntryErfassung(cDefaultText: "Firma", iMaximalLaenge: 45);
```

where OeFirma is the name of the object-instance on the page (to access it), EntryErfassung is my own class (that contains a description-label, an Entry an error-label and more) and cDefaultText is a parameter, that overtakes and set the default-text to the Entry and iMaximalaenge is a further parameter that is overtaken whereby **my class** then take care, that not more then 45 Characters are accepted for this Entry).

I have e.g. created a class with a description-label, a delete-button, an Entry and a error-label ad use it on all data-entry-forms.
If you want to change the look-and-feel of a specific control for a specific platform, you can create a "custom-render" (I have done this e.g. to change the font-size to the edit specific for iOS, as the font-sinze cannot be set in the XF-Entry control).

Hope this answers your question...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your answer in conjunction with Tristan's was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you can just specific a style in the App class, (you will need to change the app class to be made up of 2 partials: App.xaml & App.xaml.cs, and then create a ResourceDictionary to hold your customisations.

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Image" Value="MyImage.png"/>
</Style>
```

Hope that helps.

Cheers,
Tristan